# How can I prevent preloading of HTML5 Video in mac OS safari browser to reduce page load time

Tags: html, video

I have owl carousel with multiple HTML5 Videos. I have added preload="none" and it works fine in chrome & mozila but not in Mac safari version.

```
    <div id="CustomVideo" class="banner-video webview">
 <video muted="true" preload="metadata">
    <source src="demo.webm" type="video/webm">
    <source src="demo.mp4" type="video/mp4">
 </video>
</div>


 <script>
        var owl = $('.slider_owl');
        $('.slider_owl').owlCarousel({
            items: 1,
            loop: true,
            dots: false,
            video: true,
            lazyLoad:true,
            autoplay:true,
            autoplayHoverPause:false,
            autoplayTimeout:5000,   
            responsive : {
                // breakpoint from 768 up
                768 : {
                    onInitialized: function () {
                        if ($(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).length) {
                            $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element)[0].play();

                            owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
                            $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).on('ended', function () {
                                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay')
                            });
                        }
                    },
                    onTranslated: function () {
                        if ($(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).length) {
                            $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element)[0].play();
                            owl.trigger('stop.owl.autoplay');
                            $(".owl-item.active video", this.$element).on('ended', function () {
                                owl.trigger('play.owl.autoplay')
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
            }              
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: please post the relevant code

Comment: Please forgive me if you are using an html-video-specific idiom with which I'm not familiar, but "How to stop preload off" doesn't sound like English, and I'm not sure what you mean by it.

Comment: @ATomCalledStu
Thank you, for you interest.
Can you please check it.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand your question. You want to prevent the video from preloading? Or you want to enable a preload?

Comment: @ATomCalledStu I want to "preload off" main in safari browser in mac OS
because, currently in safari first download fullvideo and load entire page.
So, I want skip this step to download video.

Comment: Note that setting the `autoplay` attribute will automatically preload the video. See [MDN's article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#attr-preload): *The `autoplay` attribute has precedence over `preload`. If `autoplay` is specified, the browser would obviously need to start downloading the video for playback.* I don't know how this "owl" component works, but it does seem to be doing something with "autoplay".

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing your preload attribute to `preload=“none”,` but there are several documented issues with the preload attribute. Mainly, browsers seems to have several different instances wherein they will ignore the tag altogether, or treat the tag differently that expected. Some versions of safari do not support the metadata version of this tag, for example.

You may want to consider reducing the file size or number of videos or changing the way in which they are served to the user. You can use js to load them dynamically on page load instead of loading them directly into the markup.

Consider this article about best practices for preloading video: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/fast-playback-with-video-preload

Comment: Thank you so much!!

Comment: Yes it works, Thank You!!
But my issue still not solved for mac safari version.
Otherwise it will OKAY other browser.

Comment: preload=none works just fine in safari, can you explain the issue you’re experiencing?